# Draw and listview in same activity/screen

Tags: android, listview, android-relativelayout, draw

Hello i'm a beginner in android programming (and in stackoverflow)!

I have an activity with a RelativeLayout (i will call it rl1 to be more easy to understand) layout type. Inside of rl1 i have a custom listview with strings and images and i added another RelativeLayout inside the rl1 (i will call it rl2). rl2 sits on top of listview.
I would like to draw something on the new RelativeLayout (rl2) inside the rl1. This happens because i want to be able to draw lines and shapes and, at the same time, edit strings and images in my listview, and to do the very basic, see my custom listview (its like 1/3 of the screen for the draw stuff and 2/3 of the screen for listview; i dont want to separate this actions onto two separate activities, i want to use the same activity/screen).
How can i accomplish this? Im not walking a good path? Any ideias or web tutorials can be thrown towards me xD

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use bellow code.

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <com.multicom.pulltorefreshlistview.PullToRefreshView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
                android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                android:longClickable="false" >
            </com.multicom.pulltorefreshlistview.PullToRefreshView>

         </RelativeLayout>
```

```
        </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i couldn't make it work :P There isn't a easy way to draw only on the created layout?

Comment: My explanation was very confusing. Basically what i want to achieve is a area overlay where i can draw and keep seeing my listview =)

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem! The answer was here:

http://javandroidevelop.blogspot.pt/2012/09/all-about-surfaceview-android-lessons.html

Great tutorial! Thanks anyway nilesh patel.